# NSOperation in iOS - How to handle loops and nested NSOperation call to get Images

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

I need help understanding how to appropriate handle the following use case:

Say I'm writing a Chat app:

1. Launch App
2. Ask server (`AFHTTPRequestOperation`) to give me a list of all new messages
3. Loop through those messages to see if I need to download any images
4. If yes, then make another call to the server (`AFImageRequestOperation`) to get the image

I keep getting crashes where my managed object "message" is no longer in the same context, but I'm only using one `managedObjectContext`.

Is it because of the way I'm nesting the calls, since they are asynchronous? I am almost positive the message isn't getting deleted elsewhere, because I see it.

One thing to note is that is seems to happen when I change view controllers. I launch the app, and at the root view controller (RVC), it performs step #2 above. If I touch to go the the "`MessageListViewController`" (MLVC) before all of the images have downloaded, the associated messages for those images that didn't finish downloading suddenly have a nil `managedObjectContext`.

Below is the relevant code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:requestImageInfoURL
     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

         NSDictionary * JSONresponse = (NSDictionary *)JSON;

         if( [[[JSONresponse objectForKey:@"status"] uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"ERROR"] )
         {
             for( id<CommsObserver> observer in _observers )
                 [observer errorOccurred:[JSONresponse objectForKey:@"message"]];
         }
         else
         {
             if( [JSONresponse containsKey:@"convoMessages"] )
             {
                 NSArray * messageList = [JSON objectForKey:@"messages"];

                 for( int i = 0 ; i < messageList.count ; i++ )
                 {
                     __block ConversationMessage * message = [JSONUtility convoMessageFromJSON:[messageList objectAtIndex:i]];

                     if( !message )
                         NSLog( @"Couldn't create the new message..." );
                     else
                     {
                         message.unread = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                         [[DataController sharedController] saveContext];

                         if( (!message.text || [message.text isEqualToString:@""]) && (message.image || message.imageInfoKey) )
                         {
                             NSString * imageURL = (message.image ? [Comms urlStringForImageInfo:message.image] : [Comms urlStringForImageKey:message.imageInfoKey extension:message.imageInfoExt]);

                             NSURLRequest *requestImageURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
                             AFImageRequestOperation * imageOperation;
                             imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:requestImageURL
                                   imageProcessingBlock:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
                                       return image;
                                   } success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                       if( message.image )
                                       {
                                           NSLog( @"updating imageInfo for message" );

                                           [Utilities updateImageInfo:message.image
                                                            withImage:image
                                                            asPreview:YES
                                                          asThumbnail:YES
                                                         preserveSize:YES];
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           NSLog( @"creating a new imageInfo for message" );

                                           ImageInfo * imageInfo = [Utilities createImageInfoFromImage:image asPreview:NO asThumbnail:NO preserveSize:YES];

                                           if( imageInfo.managedObjectContext == nil )
                                               NSLog( @"imageInfo MOC is NIL" );
                                           else if( message.managedObjectContext == nil )
                                           {
                                               NSLog( @"message MOC is NIL" );

                                               message = [[DataController sharedController] convoMessageForKey:message.key];

                                               if( !message )
                                                   NSLog( @"message is NIL, meaning it wasn't found in the MOC" );
                                               else if( !message.managedObjectContext )
                                                   NSLog( @"message MOC was STILL NIL" );
                                               else
                                                   NSLog( @"problem solved..." );
                                           }

                                           if( imageInfo )
                                               [[DataController sharedController] associateImageInfo:imageInfo withMessage:message];
                                       }

                                       [[DataController sharedController] saveContext];

                                   } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog( @"Image DOWNLOAD error... \n%@" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , error] );
                                   }];

                             [imageOperation start];
                         }

                         for( id<CommsObserver> observer in _observers )
                             [observer newConvoMessages:@[message.key]];
                     }
                 } // End for loop of messageList

             } // End if JSONresponse

         } // End outer if ERROR statement

     } // End Success 

     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
         NSLog( @"Error: \n%@" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , error] );
     }
];

[operation start];
```

Comment: You should edit your title, it has nothing to do with AFNetworking.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, good point. Replaced AFNetworking with NSOperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the execution context where you invoke methods associated to a managed object context is appropriate (namely, is the *same*) as for the managed object context.

That is, when you invoke

```
 [[DataController sharedController] saveContext];
```

the thread (or dispatch queue) where the method `save:` will be executed (eventually) MUST be the same where the managed object context is associated to.

Here in this case, we can immediately conclude, that this will only work IFF a) the completion handler of AFN will execute on the main thread AND b) the managed object context is associated to the main thread, too,  OR you take care of this within the implementation of `saveContext` and use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`.

Otherwise since the execution context of a managed object context is *private*, the execution context of *any* completion handler will never match this one. Hence, you violate the concurrency rules for Core Data.

Whenever you send a message to a managed object or a managed object context you need to ensure that the *current execution context* will be the *correct* one. That is, you need to use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` and wrap accesses into the block:

```
[[DataController sharedController].managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    assert(message.managedObjectContext == [DataController sharedController].managedObjectContext);
    message.unread = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    [[DataController sharedController] saveContext];
    ...

}];
```

Note: you have to wrap *all* those accesses into either `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`, with the exception of property `objectID` of a managed object.

The `objectID` can be obtained from any thread. Thus this can be used to fetch any managed object into any context as long as you have the `objectID`.

---

A few other hints:

#### Using a Managed Object

You need to ensure that when you *use* a managed object (that is, send a message to it) that this will be executed on the same execution context which is associated to the managed object's managed object context.

That is, in order to ensure that, you use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` as follows:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
    initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Note: `context` uses a private queue.

```
__block NSManagedObject* obj;
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    obj = [context objectRegisteredForID:theObjectID];
}];
```

Assuming, the following statement will be executed on an arbitrary thread, this is unsafe:

```
NSString* name = obj.name;
```

"Unsafe", unless you know obj's managed object context has been associated to the main thread AND the above statement will also execute on the main thread. If the context uses a *private* queue, this will be *never* true unless you use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`:

Safe:

```
__block NSString* name;
[obj.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    name = obj.name;
}];
```

Obtaining the objectID is always safe from any thread:

```
NSManagedObjectID* moid = obj.objectID;  // safe from any thread
```

---

#### "Move" a managed object from one context to another:

You cannot use a managed object associated to context A, in context B. In order to "move" that object into context B you first need the `objectID` and then "fetch" this object in context B:

```
NSManagedObjectID* moid = obj.objectID

NSManagedObjectContext* otherContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
    initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

[otherContext performBlock:^{
    NSManagedObject* obj = [otherContext objectWithID: moid];
    ...
}];
```

---

#### Error Parameters

Be carefully with error parameters.

Error parameters are *always* autoreleased. `performBlockAndWait:` doesn't use an autorelease pool internally. So, you can have a __block variable *error* outside the block:

```
__block NSManagedObject* obj;
__block NSError* error;
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    obj = [context existingObjectWithID:theObjectID error:&error];
}];
if (obj==nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error:%@", error);
}
```

However `performBlock:` will use an autorelease pool internally! This has consequences:

If you use the asynchronous version `performBlock:`, you need to handle errors *within* the block:

```
__block NSManagedObject* obj;
[context performBlock:^{
    NSError* error;
    obj = [context existingObjectWithID:theObjectID error:&error];
    if (obj==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Couple of follow up questions on this (new to NSOperation AND to Core Data). Since I don't completely follow all of this (yet), [Q1]:Are you saying that if put all those accesses into `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` that my problem would go away? [Q2]:Regardless of the answer to Q1, do you think this post be a reasonable way to handle it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14526962/627465

Comment: Q1: Given the provided info, I don't know. There is a *potential* issue (see "this will only work IFF"), but there might be other issues, too. Q2: This is the right direction (using contexts with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and NSMainQueueConcurrencyType), BUT I don't full agree with this answer, since it does not setup the stack as it should, and the answer is not as precise as it should - leaving it unclear how to use a core data stack appropriate. The code sample also is incorrect as it sends `save` to a "private" context without using `performBlock:`.

Comment: I think I'm following, but a few more questions. **Using a Managed Object** - I've updated my code to create private contexts. In this example, it's created in the `success:` block, and used for the first time for the ConversationMessage object. Now, if I were to only manipulate that object in the code above, is there any need to use `performBlock:` since (1) the parent object from the mainMOC is not being modified (since I fetch it from the new temp context), and (2) I declared the context locally, meaning no other threads will know about it or have access to it?

Comment: **Using a Managed Object** - Next, when I get to the nested NSOperation to download the image, do I need to create another temp context, since that call would be on another thread?

Comment: **"Move" a managed object** - Is this not handled when saving the child context if I call `setParentContext:` on the child context and made the parent the mainMOC (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` used on the main thread)? I thought when I called save on the child context that it would be pushed to the parent automatically. Essentially, what I'm doing in the background in all of my calls is (1) create a temporary child context; (2) setting it's parent to the main context for the persistence store; (3) fetching on the child context; (4) updating on child context; (5) saving child context.

Comment: Creating a managed object will alter internal data structures of the context. If you execute this on some random thread, and irrespective of the probability that at the same time the context executes other tasks on its *associated* queue, this IS still a potential race condition. The same is imperative for altering the managed object's state, regardless of the probability that something *actually* goes wrong.

Comment: If you execute events for context X, and this requires *Core Data itself* to access  X's parent context, Core Data will take care itself that it executes any task on the parent's context queue, using `[x.parentContext performBlock:]`

Comment: You can invoke `[context performBlock:^{...}]` and `[context performBlockAndWait:^{...}]` on *any* thread. Well, you MUST.