# NSArray with NSManagedObject's relationships faults on second display in UITableView

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm parsing a bunch of data and mapping it to `Core Data` `NSManagedObject`s. I pass these to my `UITableViewController` in an `NSArray` which I use as the `dataSource`.

The `NSManagedObject`s are often linked to other `NSManagedObject`s with relationships. Most of these entities that are linked via a relationship have the content I need to display (depending on the relationship). Initially the `UITableView` displays the content no problem. As soon as I start scrolling and the cell is re-used or if I scroll back to the same location, the cell is blank (I'm just debugging right now, so only displaying content as a string).

I'm logging the NSManagedObject and get the following before scrolling:

```
<NewPost: 0xd5dcc00> (entity: NewPost; id: 0xd5dcc60 <x-coredata:///NewPost/t63931035-BB67-467D-8598-CAD8563BA5DC267> ; 
data: {
   group = "0xd5b7a50 <x-coredata:///Group/t63931035-BB67-467D-8598-CAD8563BA5DC265>";
   newPostAttributedText = "0xd5e78d0 <x-coredata:///AttributedText/t63931035-BB67-467D-8598-CAD8563BA5DC269>";
   newPostSection = "0xe85cc70 <x-coredata://3DE41B33-C64E-44C4-9F86-98DF3C6AD700/PostSection/p7>";
   newPostCreator = "0xd297050 <x-coredata://3DE41B33-C64E-44C4-9F86-98DF3C6AD700/Person/p9>";
})
```

When scrolling and showing the same object I see the following in my log:

```
<NewPost: 0xd5dcc00> (entity: NewPost; id: 0xe8b3cc0 <x-coredata://3DE41B33-C64E-44C4-9F86-98DF3C6AD700/NewPost/p75> ; 
data: <fault>)
```

Why does the relationship fault when I need to re-use the cell or re-display the same data?

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that each managed object's context is associated to either the main thread (thread confinement) or to the main queue? Also, did you fetch the objects into the context? Well, one could have a context A whose parent is the main context whose parent is the root context (A ->main->root), then delete objects from a different context B  (B-> root) and save it persistently. Now, objects in context A might be deleted but they still exist as "registered" managed objects in that context, but are faults. Fetch context A, in order to update it.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Looks like it was an issue with context. I am using MagicalRecord and stupidly used `saveWithBlock:` and of course put all the objects into the array which I then dispatch to the main thread which causes the faults to happen. If you answer the question, I will gladly accept.

Comment: I'll try to formulate an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to ensure that each managed object's context is associated to either the *main thread* (thread confinement) or the *main queue*. (Note: a managed object has a property `managedObjectContext`)

   If you access managed objects in the main thread, for example to render the content with UIKit, their managed object context MUST be associated to the main thread respectively the main queue.

   Also, it makes sense to have only *one* context for the objects and its related objects.
2. Additionally, you need to ensure that your context (in this case the "main context") is actually up to date. That means, you possibly need to fetch objects which retrieves them from the persistent store if required, and it also updates the set of objects (when using a predicate).

   This above is required for example when you have a context M (the main context associated to the main queue) whose parent is the root context (M -> root), where the persistent store is handled. Then, delete objects from a different context B (B-> root) and save it persistently. Now, objects in context Main might be deleted but they still exist as "registered" managed objects in that context, but are faults. Fetch context M (main context), in order to update it.

   **Note:** You are better off using a `NSFetchedResultsController` in order to handle updates.

**Caution:** When using MagicalRecord, you may end up with a Core Data stack, where the "default context" handles the persistent store and is also associated to the main thread. Children contexts will execute on a private queue and will have set the main context as its parent. IMHO, this is suboptimal.

Take also a look here on SO [NSOperation in iOS - How to handle loops and nested NSOperation call to get Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171875/nsoperation-in-ios-how-to-handle-loops-and-nested-nsoperation-call-to-get-imag/20174128#20174128), for dealing with managed objects.

Comment: Thanks for answering in such detail, so it hopefully helps other people. It was indeed an issue with contexts!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting to **NO** the **returnsObjectsAsFaults** property in **NSFetchRequest** object:

```
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with my tables doing strange things when a cell is scrolled off screen and then back on.  My usual work-around is to not reuse cells.  Note that if you try doing this with very large tables, there may be some performance loss.  The tables I've used this on are never more than twice the size of the screen, and I've never noticed any performance lag, but I imaging if you are doing it with 100s of rows or something you could run into trouble.

If you want to go this way, the general idea is:

- Call a new method from `viewDidLoad` (or something similar) that creates all the cells for the whole table (on screen and off) - this method is usually pretty similar to whatever was originally being done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
- Put the cells into an `NSMutableArray` ivar as they are made.
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just return the cell from that array.

It's probably not the ideal solution, but it has worked for me pretty well in the past when my cells are misbehaving when they get reused.

Comment: Well, you should really re-use cells in a table view. I would suggest to hunt the actually issue and fix that. ;)